# If given a Python class, how can I run it and see what it does?

Tags: python

```
import math

class Vector:

  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x= x
    self.y =y

  def add(self,other):
    new_x = self.x + other.x
    new_y = self.y + other.y
    return Vector(new_x,new_y)

  def subtract(self,other):
    new_x = self.x - other.x
    new_y = self.y - other.y
    return Vector(new_x,new_y)

  def scale(self,factor):
    new_x = self.x * factor
    new_y = self.y * factor
    return Vector(new_x,new_y)

  def length(self,other):
    r_squared = self.x ** 2 + self.y **2
    return Vector(r_squared)
```

I've been trying to test this code that I was given, how am I able to test this using some numbers so that I am able to learn to understand what each function in this code actually does. I am able to see what it does from looking at the code but I also want to reassure that what I am predicting it to do is actually what it does.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's seems that you are trying to overload built in function, read about this here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0220__Class/OperatorOverloadingaddsubmuldiv.htm or google "python overload add sub"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a checker for your code at the very end of yor file:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    vec1 = Vector(0, 0)
    vec2 = Vector(2,2)
    vec3 = vec1.add(vec2)
    print(vec1, vec2, vec3)
    #add other tests
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an override to a built in function in the Vector class for printing instances in a human readable way.

```
def __repr__(self):
  return 'Vector: ({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)
```

Then you might want to fix the `length` function. It should only return a number and not another `Vector`. Additionally, it should return the square root of the sum. For example the vector (3, 4) should have a length of 5, not 25. Also, the `length` method does not need vector supplied as a param.

Once these are fixed up you can add this to the bottom of the file and run the script in the terminal like so: `python vec.py`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  v1 = Vector(0,0)
  v2 = Vector(3,4)

  print('v1', v1)
  print('v2', v2)
  print('v1 + v2', v1.add(v2))
  print('v2.length', v2.length())
```